# On Sliding down the SlideDialog I am getting RederFlex overflowed error on the bottom. Can you suggest any method to resolve this issue?

Tags: flutter, dart

**I am using slide_popup_dialog package and calling this dialog on a button call. Below is the code**

```
showSlideDialog(context: context, child: Column(children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height*0.50,
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
                                    onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newdate) {
                  print(newdate);
                                    },
                                  ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                                          child: RaisedButton(
                  child: const Text("Confirm"),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                      onPressed: () {
                        print("Confirm");
                      }),
                    )
                                  ], mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center));
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the problem is with the package it self. If found same issue reported on the github repository too. [Here is the link](https://github.com/dhimasdewanto/slide_popup_dialog/issues/2).

I tried the solution given there of using Expanded and SingleChildScrollView widget and it works. Here is the modified code. Hope it helps.

```
    showSlideDialog(
    context: context,
    child: Expanded(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.50,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: CupertinoDatePicker(
                backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
                onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newdate) {
                  print(newdate);
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: RaisedButton(
                child: const Text("Confirm"),
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8.0)),
                onPressed: () {
                  print("Confirm");
                }),
          )
        ], mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center),
      ),
    ));
```

Comment: Thanx @DevKage, it worked. Although there is still a little bug. if you try to slide down the slideDialog until the very end of the Dialog then it gives the same error but that is barely visible. If you find any solution to that little bug, please post the solution.

Comment: Yes I also noticed that bug. It happens if the scrolling is very slow. I am not sure why that might be happening.